# Cannot convert bytes output to string while running praat script through subprocess python

Tags: python

```
sound_offset_time = subprocess.check_output(praat_command_str, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
```

gives output

```
# Result: - #
```

Another command

```
process = subprocess.Popen(praat_command_str, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
```

gives output:

```
('-\x006\x00.\x008\x001\x004\x006\x006\x000\x008\x009\x006\x003\x001\x007\x006\x006\x002\x00\r\x00\n\x00', None)
```

which I cannot convert from bytes to string, still obtaining '-'.
Correct output, if run from commandline is

```
-6.814660896317662
```

Comment: I know it's been a while but do you remember how you fixed your problem ? I'm doing this but i still have the issue `output = subprocess.check_output(praat_cmd).decode('utf-16-le')`:

Comment: Sorry, late answer. Did you try`shell=True` in `check output`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but yeah i tried, without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your command is sending output in `utf-16` form, but you're trying to decode it as `utf-8`.